# How to desc order date field in while loop

Tags: php, mysql

How to `DESC` order `Date` field in while loop
How to `DESC` order `Date` field by using while loop select data
First We need ASC ORDER & After We need Display DESC ORDER Date

```
$start_date="SELECT user_registered FROM wp_users ORDER BY user_registered ASC LIMIT 1";

$date_result=$wpdb->get_results($start_date) or die(mysqli_error());

$date =  date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date_result[0]->user_registered));

$end_date = date('Y-m-d');

while ($end_date >= $date)
{
    echo $date;

    $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
}
```

we need desc order `echo $date`

Answer (score 1):

I think you may use like below .

```
$array = array();
while ($end_date >= $date) {

   $array[]=$date;

   $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
}
echo '<pre/>';
print_r(array_reverse($array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while( $end_date >= $date )
{
    echo $end_date;
    $end_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 day", strtotime( $end_date ) ) );
}
```

Comment: How it will get the required result ?

Comment: He want print only ("we need desc order echo $date").